# Change of basis, transition matrices, and representation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

The following four questions were presented to me on an introductory-level linear algebra study guide. Before diving into some conceptual questions I have, here are the questions and my attempts at solving them:

> $T$ is the projection onto the vector $\vec{w}=(3,1)$ in $R^2$ which is given as the following: $$T(\vec{x})=\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{w}}{\vec{w}\cdot \vec{w}}\vec{w}$$

For simplicity, I will reduce $T(\vec{x})$ to $$T(\vec{x})=\frac{\vec{x}\cdot(3,1)}{10}(3,1)$$

> (a) Find the standard representation matrix $A$ corresponding to the linear transformation above.

$$T[(1,0)]=\frac{(1,0) \cdot (3,1)}{10}(3,1)=(\frac{9}{10},\frac{3}{10})$$
$$T[(0,1)]=\frac{(0,1) \cdot (3,1)}{10}(3,1)=(\frac{3}{10},\frac{1}{10})$$

Thus the standard representation matrix A is

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{9}{10} & \frac{3}{10} \\
\frac{3}{10} & \frac{1}{10} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

> (b) Find the transition matrix P from the non-standard basis $B=\{(1,-1),(0,1)\}$ to the standard basis.

Choosing $B'=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ to represent the standard matrix, the transition matrix $P$ from $B$ to $B'$ can be found by rewriting $[B'\space B]$ as $[I^3\space P]$.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

> (c) By using the formula $A'=P^{-1}AP$, find the representation matrix $A'$ that corresponds to the linear transformation above, relative to the basis $B$.

If $[B'\space B]$ reduces to $[I^3\space P]$, then $[B\space B']$ should reduce $[I^3\space P^{-1}]$.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

And finally $$A'=P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{9}{10} & \frac{3}{10} \\ \frac{3}{10} & \frac{1}{10} \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{6}{10} & \frac{3}{10} \\ \frac{8}{10} & \frac{4}{10} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

> (d) Find $T(\vec{v})$ relative to basis $B$ where $\vec{v}=(7,4)$ by using $A'$.

While normally we might use the equation $[T(\vec{v})]_{B}=A'[\vec{v}]_{B'}$, since $B'$ is the $2\times 2$ Identity Matrix, we can simplify it to

$$[T(\vec{v})]_{B}=A'\vec{v}=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{6}{10} & \frac{3}{10} \\ \frac{8}{10} & \frac{4}{10} \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{27}{5} \\ \frac{36}{5} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

---

Firstly, what I am curious about is the choice of $P$ and $P^{-1}$. Specifically, will $P^{-1}$ always represent the transition matrix from some basis to the basis we are trying to solve $T(\vec{v})$ with respect to? Order matters when multiplying matrices (i.e. $AB$ is not necessarily equal to $BA$) so what I am getting at is that there must be a reason we picked $P$ to be the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$.

My next question is about why I am able to get two different values for $A'$. I had the impression that I solved (d) incorrectly, so I tried it another way, where $A'=[[T[(1,0)]]_{B} | [T[(0,1)]]_{B}]$.

$T[(1,0)]=(\frac{9}{10}, \frac{3}{10})$ and $T[(0,1)]=(\frac{3}{10}, \frac{1}{10})$ so

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}[T[(1,0)]]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{9}{10} \\ \frac{3}{10} \\ \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow [T[(1,0)]]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{9}{10} \\ \frac{12}{10} \\ \end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}[T[(0,1)]]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{3}{10} \\ \frac{1}{10} \\ \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow [T[(0,1)]]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{3}{10} \\ \frac{4}{10} \\ \end{bmatrix}$

therefore

$$A'=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{9}{10} & \frac{3}{10} \\
\frac{12}{10} & \frac{4}{10} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which, interestingly enough, is the same as $P^{-1}A$. Of course, if I plug this into the equation I used in part (d), I get a completely different answer. However, I know almost certainly that, at least for the method of obtaining $A'$ shown right above, that the equation in (d) should work in finding $[T(\vec{v})]_{B}$.

What I am thinking now is that I am either solving the wrong equation for part (d) or that I messed up somewhere in finding my transition matrices. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked your calculations, but your second method of computing $A'$ is wrong. By definition,

$$ A' = [T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}} = [[T(1,-1)]_{\mathcal{B}} \, | \, [T(0,1)]_{\mathcal{B}}] $$

and not what you wrote. You take each element of the basis $\mathcal{B}$, apply $T$ to it, represent the result with respect to the **same** basis $\mathcal{B}$ and put in in a column. Instead, you have taken the standard basis, applied $T$ to it and then represented the result with respect to a **different** basis.

---

Regarding your question about $P$, there is a notorious ambiguity between different authors regarding what is called "a change of basis matrix from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{C}$". What some authors call $P$ might be called $P^{-1}$ by other authors and the formula for one author will look like $A' = P^{-1}AP$ while for another it will look like $A' = PAP^{-1}$. In my opinion, the change of basis formula should be written as

$$ [T]_{\mathcal{B}} = [\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'} [T]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B'}} [\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}. $$

Notice the "cancellation across diagonals" property which makes the formula easy to remember. Then, $P = [\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}$ is the matrix whose columns are the elements of the basis $\mathcal{B}$, represented in the basis $\mathcal{B}'$. By the formula $[\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} [v]_{\mathcal{B}} = [v]_{\mathcal{B}'}$, this matrix allows us to convert a representation of a vector in the basis $\mathcal{B}'$ to the representation of the same vector in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ by multiplying the representation $[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$ with $P$. This point of view makes it harder to confuse $P$ and $P^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah, redoing $A'$ the way you suggested yields the same answer as (c). I had done another problem with $T: R^2 \rightarrow R^3$ and two non-standard bases where the latter method I tried had been valid (I think...), but apparently not in this case as the dimension remains the same throughout the problem. And I agree that this representation of transition matrices is rather confusing because, as you suggested, it's relative to the author's intentions. It was made particularly confusing by the fact that my professor used $B$ for the non-standard basis.

Comment: @Jordan: The notation above can explain why the approach "worked" with $T \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ and doesn't work now. For $T \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, the domain and range are different! So it makes no sense to represent $T$ with respect to the same basis in the domain and range and you must have two different bases, apply $T$ to one and represent it with the other. However, with $T \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, the notation $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ means $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}$ while you have calculated

Comment: $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}$. As an exercise, write the relation between $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}$ and $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}$ in terms of $P$ and see that you get your interesting observation.